# dynamic picture for documentation

Tags: image, documentation, level-of-detail

do you know a tool to present a "dynamic picture" of software architecture with a level of detail? So that you can zoom in and out and see different levels of detail. In general this picture could contain the architecture of an entire company but the overview is achieved by zoom, expand and collaps.

very simple example:
the highest abstraction level is [image: level-1]

then you zoom in into *search* from level-1 [image: level-2]

then you zoom even more into *database* from level-2 [image: level-3]

Comment: If your question is "could you suggest a tool to do X", it's almost certainly off-topic here. Ask on [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: ok, thanks, wasn't aware of that. posted the question over there: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87968/dynamic-picture-for-documentation